# Secure two way hashing technique

Tags: php, sql, password-encryption

I am currently developing a Document Authentication System and I want the Passwords of the users to be hashed or encrypted ..

So my question is, what is the best and most secure TWO WAY Hashing or Encrypting method I will use ..

Comment: What do you mean by "two-way"? If it is a hash, it is definitely one-way by definition. Use [`password_hash`](https://php.net/password-hash).

Comment: Hashing is one way only. Encryption is two way. Passwords should only ever be hashed. For php, use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: two way are usually insecure, better use one way which is `password_hash();' and `password_verify();`

Comment: @PEMapModder I mean two way encryption ..

Comment: Don't ever do this! There is no reason for storing passwords unhashed (even if encrypted).

Comment: Use `two-tier` authentication... Menaing you'll have to authenticate yourself on the website by password and through, e.g., an sms-token. And beef up the verification process like @MasivuyeCokile suggests...

Comment: @Masivuye Cokile i want my password to be two way its because i want the password of my user to be secured and at the same ENABLE THE ADMINISTRATOR TO VIEW THE PASSWORDS OF THE USERS INCASE THEY FORGET IT ..

Comment: No, thats wrong, why would you let an admin view user's passwords, if a user forget their password you should have a method to recover/reset passwords.... Remember most hackers are the admins

Comment: @Masivuye Cokile thank you for your advice sir, I now understand what really the concept of the hashing and encryption .. i though they are thesame .. haha ..

Comment: can anybody tell me what is the best and secure hashing method?

Comment: @toomelette you should **never** let **anyone** see passwords **at all**. paswords are *not meant* to be recovered. if someone forgot his password, **give him a new one**. oh, and the best hashing method for passwords was already mentioned: `password_hash()`

Comment: Please read http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php  and password.  
http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: can anybody give an example? ..

Comment: based on my research their are different way of hashing like sha256, sha512, md5 etc .. what is the most appropriate??

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann thank you for your advice sir .. i will do it for my system ..

Answer (score 2):

As it has been suggested in the comments above the best and easy way is to use `password_hash();` and `password_verify();` more info is available in the php.net website, and also make use of prepared statements either with mysqli or pdo in my basic user registration i made use of PDO.

Please not this is just a basic example of how to use password_hash and password_verify();

we will use the `password_hash()` upon registration and password_verify() upon login

**db.php**

```
<?php


    $server="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";

    try{

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=sytemDb",$username,$password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }catch(PDOException $exc){

        error_log($exc);
    }
?>
```

The above script makes connection to our database.

**register.php**

```
<?php

    include 'db.php';
    $errors="";
    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

        //check if values are not empty

        if(empty($_POST['email'])){

            die("please enter email");
            $errors++;
        }else{

            $email = $_POST['email'];

            //then check for valid email
        }
    }
    if(empty($_POST['upass'])){

        die("enter password");
        $errors++;
    }else{

        $password = $_POST['upass'];

        $hash = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);//hashing password
    }

    if($errors <=0){

        //no errors save to db

        $stmt= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES(?,?)");
        $stmt->execute(array($username,$hash));

        echo "User registered";
    }


?>







<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Registration</title>
</head>
<body>


    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Ente Username">
        <input type="password" name="upass" placeholder="Enter Password">
        <button type="submit" name="register">Register</button>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    include 'db.php';

    if(isset($_POST['login'])){


        if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['pass'])){

            die("enter password or username");
        }else{

            $uname = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['pass'];
        }

        try {

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT userid,password,username from users where username = ?");
            $stmt->bindValue(1,$uname);
            $stmt->execute();

            $results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if(count($results) > 0){
                //if username is correct continue check entered password against saved hash

                foreach ($results as $row) {

                    if(password_verify($password,$row['password'])){
                        //password and saved hash match go to dashboard

                        echo "login success";
                        $_SESSION['user']= $row['userid'];
                        header("refresh:5;url=dashboard");
                    }else{

                        echo "username and password does not match";
                    }
                }
            }else{

                echo "username and password does not match";
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {


            error_log($e);

        }
    }






?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="">

    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Enter password">

    <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This should do its very basic password hash is available in the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

password_verify() also available [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Please make use of php 5.6 or above of which u were supposed to already do.

That's about it. Hope this will point you to the correct direction.

> NB: Always verify input from the user, don't forget to filter and
>   sanitize the input then prepare a statement to save to the db.

incase a user forget a password, well there are many ways to reset the user password, one basic way is to have an autho token column on ur db.

The following way is very basic for beginners just to kickoff your career lol ;)

```
<?php

function ForgetPassword()
{

    try {
        //search the user on the database
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT email,userid,firstname,lastname from users where email = ?");
        $stmt->bindvalue($email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (count($results) > 0) { //user found generate authentication token
            foreach ($results as $row):
                $userid     = base64_encode($row['userID']);
                $randomAuth = md5(uniqid(rand()));
                $dataUpdate = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users set auth_token = ? where email = ?");
                $dataUpdate->execute(array(
                    $randomAuth,
                    $row['email']
                ));

                //send reset link to the user

                $link = "<a href=\"" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "resetpassword?id=$userid&token=$randomAuth\">Reset your password</a>";

                $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
                $header .= 'From: <>' . "\r\n";

                $message = "<p> Hello " . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . "</p>";
                $message .= "<p> You have requested to reset your password your password</p>";
                $message .= "<p>" . $link . "</p>";

                if (mail(($row['email']), "Password Reset", $message, $header)) {

                    $successMessage = "Reset link sent to the provided email address";

                } else {

                    error_log("cound not send message");
                }
            endforeach;
        } else {

            $successMessage = "Reset link sent to the provided email address";
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {

        error_log($ex);
    }

}
?>
```

**Then reset passwordpage**

```
<?php

function resetPassword()
{

    if (isset($_GET['code']) && isset($_GET['token'])) {

        $code  = base64_decode($_GET['code']);
        $token = $_GET['token'];

        if (isset($_POST['resetpassword'])) {

            //check empty fields

            if (empty($_POST['newpassword'])) {

                $errorMessage = "enter password";
                $errors++;
                return $errorMessage;
            } else {

                $password = $_POST['newpassword'];

                $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //password encryption
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['newpassword']) && empty($_POST['confirmpassword'])) {

                $errorMessage = "Please confirm your password";
                $errors++;
                return $errorMessage();
            }

            if (!empty($_POST['confirmpassword']) && $_POST['confirmpassword'] !== $_POST['newpassword']) {

                return "Passwords does not match";
                $errors++;
            }

        }

        if ($errors <= 0) {

            try {

                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("Update users set password = ? where userID = ? AND auth_token = ?");
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    $hash,
                    $code,
                    $token
                ));

                return "Password successfully changed.. Redirecting to login page";

                $update = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users set aut_token = NULL where userID = ? ");
                $update->bindValue(1, $code);
                $update->execute();

                header("refresh=3:url;login");

            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {

                error_log($e->getMessage());
            }

        }

    } else {
        //token code error
        return "The link have expired, please go back and request a new one";

    }


}
?>
```

Comment: can you show me the code about how to verify?

Comment: @toomelette answer updated.

Comment: thank you so much for the help sir i really appreciate it ..

Comment: cool, if the answer helped u, u can mark it and upvote.

Comment: sir one more question .. is this method the most secure? .. i heard some hashing alogarithms like the mentioned above .. is it more secure to use those alogarithms or i will stick to password_hash() method?

Comment: Yes its secure man.